# htaccess redirection to sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with a default index page. I want to use .htaccess to redirect the users to a sub-folder on the website without knowing that they are redirected.

I want to redirect `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/sub-folder` .. But what the user will see is `www.example.com` .. whenever the user goes to anything within `sub-folder` they just see `www.example.com` and the location they are at.

So if they go to `www.example.com/sub-folder/1.php` they just see `www.example.com/1.php` .. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^sub-folder /sub-folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your answer, but now all the images, css, etc .. are not linked correctly!! How can I correct this?

Comment: You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: If that doesn't work then you need to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.